# Calling one bean from another bean and setting the value to the bean and display from another bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I have a dialog which is backed by a managed bean `@RequestScoped` `'A'`. And I am calling the dialog from another bean `'B'` also `@RequestScoped`. So I am using `@ManagedProperty` for calling `'A'` from `'B'`. I have set the values(object,variable,etc..) of `'A'` from `'B'` for display which will depend on an object of `'B'`. All the values are set correctly but when the dialog opens, the values I set for `'A'` are not displayed.

How to achieve this goal ??

I mean calling a dialog backed by one bean and setting the values of backed bean from another bean ??

I have used a button which is on a `p:dataTable` row :

```
<p:column headerText="Actions">
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View"
process="@this"
oncomplete="receiptViewWidget.show()"
action="#{receiptRepoMB.forReceiptDialog}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener
target="#{receiptRepoMB.receiptDetObj}" value="#{rd}" />
</p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

The dialog is displayed but values are not displayed.

Code snippet for `'B'` :

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{receiptMB}")
private ReceiptMB receiptMB;
public ReceiptMB getReceiptMB() {
return receiptMB;
}
public void setReceiptMB(ReceiptMB receiptMB) {
this.receiptMB = receiptMB;
}
public void forReceiptDialog(){
ReceiptModel receiptObj = receiptDetObj.getReceiptModel();
receiptMB.setReceiptSummary(receiptObj);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add for each property get and set. Post your java code.

Comment: OK, I am posting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `update=":receiptViewForm"` in the `p:commandButton`, which is the form id of the dialog.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View"
process="@this" oncomplete="receiptViewWidget.show()"
action="#{receiptRepoMB.forReceiptDialog}"
update=":receiptViewForm">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{receiptRepoMB.receiptDetObj}" 
value="#{rd}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

And it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the value of A used from B will be lost when you try to access it.

I would recommend you to define A with a longer scope to keep its value when called by B. (something like @ViewScoped should work).

```
@ViewScoped
public class A {}

@RequestScoped
public class B {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{a}")
    private A a;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try and reply.